# Cache android webview for minify js and css calls too

Tags: javascript, android, css, caching, webview

In my webpage, i have enabled minify js and css calls.  I have enabled the caching for android webview for faster performance using following

```
 mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //mWebView.addJavascriptInterface();
    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavascriptInterface(getActivity(), StartFragment.this.getActivity()), "MyJavascriptInterface");

    String UserAgent = "Wifog android-" + versionCodestr + "/" + versionName;
    mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(mWebView.getSettings().getUserAgentString() + " " + UserAgent);
    //in this call i set the webview client and the calls to process
    setWebViewClient();
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
    {
        @Override
        public void onReachedMaxAppCacheSize(long requiredStorage, long quota, WebStorage.QuotaUpdater quotaUpdater) {
            quotaUpdater.updateQuota(requiredStorage*2);
        }
    });

    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024 * 1024 * 8);
    String appCachePath = getContext().getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
    System.out.println("App- cache paht webview:  "+appCachePath);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(appCachePath);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        mWebView.getSettings().setDatabasePath("/data/data/" + mWebView.getContext().getPackageName() + "/databases/");
    }
```

But still the minify calls for the page are not being cached and hits again and again the server. How can i handle this in android ?

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try:

```
mWebView.clearCache(false);
```

and if it still doesn't work

```
Method m1 = WebSettings.class.getMethod("setAppCacheEnabled", new Class[]{Boolean.TYPE});
                m6.invoke(ws, Boolean.TRUE);
```

in this `ws` is your `WebSettings` object

Comment: thanks .. but this did not help.. still those minify js and css calls are here

Comment: you can save these files in your assets folder

Comment: what is the size of files?

Comment: not as of now. coz they are to be changed on web too

Comment: @beginner have you got your answer?

Comment: yes the changes were made on the minify settings for web and then  the minify calls were handled. no luck on app side ..But thanks a lot

Comment: glad to you find the solution. If my answer help you upto some extent please upvote. Thanks